# How to prevent dialogs from showing when screen rotates

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

Hey guys I am building an app that loads data from mysql through json. While data loads, a progress dialog is showing. When the loading is complete the dialog dismisses. But when I change screen rotation it shows up again and it loads the data again. How can I prevent this from happening??. And also the same happens to all alert dialogs that I use. Any help please?

My code:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            if(!pDialog.isShowing()){
                pDialog.show();
            }else{
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            if(!onAboutPressed().isShowing()){
                onAboutPressed().show();
            }else{
                onAboutPressed().dismiss();
            }
            if(!onAlertMobileData().isShowing()){
                onAlertMobileData().show();
            }else{
                onAlertMobileData().dismiss();
            }
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }
        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            if(!pDialog.isShowing()){
                pDialog.show();
            }else{
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            if(!onAboutPressed().isShowing()){
                onAboutPressed().show();
            }else{
                onAboutPressed().dismiss();
            }
            if(!onAlertMobileData().isShowing()){
                onAlertMobileData().show();
            }else{
                onAlertMobileData().dismiss();
            }
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }
    }
```

I finally fixed it. it just needed as well in the manifest.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Any help will be welcomed and much appreciated.

Comment: In onConfigChange method, dimiss the dialogs and then show it once you change your layout according to the rotation

Comment: how to check if screen has rotated??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest, in an activity/fragment activity tag, please add the following,

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Above line will notify your activity/fragmentactivity when there is an orientation change. In order for you to do something on it, you need to override the following method in your activity,

```
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

     if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){

    Log.e("On Config Change","LANDSCAPE");
}else{

    Log.e("On Config Change","PORTRAIT");
}

}
```

Hope this helps

EDIT:

Please see the complete code below,

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.android.customviews.R;

public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    Dialog mDialog = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle pSavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.openButton)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View pV) {
                mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(TestActivity.this, "", "Please Wait...");
                new WasteTime().execute(null, null, null);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration pNewConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(pNewConfig);

        if (mDialog != null && mDialog.isShowing()) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (pNewConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
            Log.e("On Config Change", "LANDSCAPE");
        }
    }

    class WasteTime extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... pParams) {

            final int timeWaster = 10000;
            for (int i = 0; i < timeWaster; i++) {
                Log.e("Wasting Time", i + "milliseconds wasted");
            }

            return null;
        }

    }



}
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.android.activities.TestActivity"
            android:theme="@style/ApplicationTheme_ActionBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This is what I did. I just forgot to dismiss a dialog properly. But rest is working. However if you are using a fragment then that might not work for you as it is for an activity or a Fragment Activity.

Comment: well i editted my answer.. can u please check it??? nothing happed still remains the same..

Comment: check it above please.

Comment: thanks alot man but i fixed it also.. just check my last 2 rows in my question...thanks alot anyway you saved the day....

Comment: So when I told you to add your manifest. I meant it to see if you added the orientation in your tag as well. Kudos :)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways:

- **Retaining the state on the configuration change**. This means that you would need to store the current state of your `Fragment` in the `savedInstance` `Bundle` and restore its state once the change has happened. This would imply that you don't call again the `.show()` on your `ProgressDialog` object, but keep its state. This is the recommended way to go.
- **Handle the configuration change yourself**. This will prevent `Android` from restarting your `Activity`/`Fragment` during certain configuration changes and receive a callback when the configurations change, this way you can manually update your activity as necessary. *This is the **discouraged** way to go and should be used as the last resource*.

Source (and very recommended reading): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html